# INVALID_ARGUMENT error while configuring envoy proxy

Tags: amazon-ecs, envoyproxy

I am trying to set up an envoy proxy in my ECS service. I see the below logs in the task.

```
Unable to parse JSON as proto (INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid JSON in envoy.config.bootstrap.v3.Bootstrap @ 
static_resources.listeners[0].filter_chains.filters[0].typed_config: message google.protobuf.Any, near 1:745 (offset 744): in legacy mode, 
missing @type in Any is only allowed for an empty object): {"admin":{"access_log_path":"/dev/null","address":{"socket_address":
{"port_value":8081,"address":"0.0.0.0"}}},"static_resources":{"clusters":
[{"lb_policy":"round_robin","connect_timeout":"0.5s","load_assignment":{"endpoints":[{"lb_endpoints":[{"endpoint":{"address":{"socket_address":
{"port_value":8080,"address":"127.0.0.1"}}}}]}],"cluster_name":"local_service"},"type":"strict_dns","name":"local_service"}],"listeners":[{"address":{"socket_address":{"address":"0.0.0.0","port_value":443}},"filter_chains":{"tls_context":{"common_tls_context":{"tls_certificates":
[{"certificate_chain":{"filename":"/etc/ssl/my-aws-public.crt"},"private_key":{"filename":"/etc/ssl/my-aws-private.key"}}]}},"filters":[{"name":"envoy.http_connection_manager","typed_config":
{"stat_prefix":"ingress_http","codec_type":"auto","http_filters":[{"config":{},"name":"envoy.router"}],"route_config":{"name":"local_route","virtual_hosts":[{"name":"service","routes":
[{"route":{"cluster":"local_service"},"match":
{"prefix":"/"}}],"domains":["*"]}]}}}]}}]}}
```

This is my envoy.yaml configuration file

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 443
    filter_chains:
      tls_context:
        common_tls_context:
          tls_certificates:
          - certificate_chain:
              filename: "/etc/ssl/my-aws-public.crt"
            private_key:
              filename: "/etc/ssl/my-aws-private.key"
      filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: service
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: local_service
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: local_service
    connect_timeout: 0.5s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: local_service
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 8080

admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8081
```

I have used the documentation to create the template but not sure why I am getting this error.

Please help me to troubleshoot the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I am using this documentation to create an envoy proxy to terminate tls connection on ecs container. I think the configuration for the envoy proxy is outdated. Could anyone help to correct the envoy configuration.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/maintaining-transport-layer-security-all-the-way-to-your-container-using-the-application-load-balancer-with-amazon-ecs-and-envoy/